# Why does an interface member that depends on an inferred generic argument resolve to `unknown`?

Tags: typescript, generics

MCVE:

```
interface MyVal<T> { 
  value: T;
}

interface MyList<U> { 
  value: U[];

  // Other members that need U directly
}

type MyType<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? MyList<U> : MyVal<T>;

const foo = <T>(val: MyType<T>, cb: (x: T)=>void) => {
  cb(val.value);
}
```

The code produces the following error on the `cb(val.value)` line:

> Argument of type 'T | unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.

I know I can resolve this via `cb(val.value as T);`, or by passing `T` as a second generic parameter to `MyList` and have the `value` member of `MyList` explicitly typed. However, neither of those are particularly clean, and it feels like the code should work as written.

So my question is: Is there something I'm misunderstanding about typescript's inference logic that's causing `val.value` to be inferred as `T | unknown[]` instead of `T` in this context?

Also: Is there a clean way to tackle this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: As written this doesn't work because TS tends to defer evaluation of conditional types that depend on as-yet-unspecified generic type parameters.  The compiler just can't do the higher-order analysis to see that `MyType<T>['value']` has any useful relationship with `T` other than `T | unknown[]`.  Personally, I'd be explicit and tell the compiler that `val` is expected to be `{value: T}` in addition to whatever else you know, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEVYZN).  If that helps I can write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, I considered that, but there are too many functions like `foo()` in my code for this to be scalable, I'm currently going towards something along [these](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8yPw) lines.

Comment: Also, the `unknown` comes from an eager property resolution strategy for generics that sometimes throws away information, see [microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181).  I might write up an answer anyway just to get this info out there in a non-ephemeral way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we should check it out from the final result. Bellow is your code

```
interface MyVal<T> { 
  value: T;
}

interface MyList<U> { 
  value: U[];
}

type MyType<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? MyList<U> : MyVal<T>;

const foo = function<T>(val: MyType<T>, cb: (x: T)=>void) {
  cb(val.value);
}
```

---

We can try the following examples to sort out the logic.

**EX1**
In this example, `T` is `number`, then `val.value` should be `number` type

```
foo<number>({value: 1}, (x)=>{})
```

**EX2**
When `T` is `string[]`, `val.value` will be `string[]` type

```
foo<string[]>({value: ['str']}, (x)=>{})
```

**EX3**
However, when `T` comes to `[string, number]`, `val.value` will be `(string | number)[]` type. In this case, there are two options, so `Type inference` can't understand exactly what type you mean. That's why `val.value` is inferred as `T | unknown[]`

```
foo<[string, number]>({value: ['str']}, (x)=>{})
```

To solve that, and limit the array that only includes one type when `T` is Array,
you can try this solution, hope it helps you :)

```
const foo = function<T>(val: MyType<T> extends {value: T} ? MyType<T> : never, cb: (x: T)=>void) {
    cb(val.value);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, now you can try it out